# Join condition of a LEFT JOIN seems to be ignored for the left table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

My query seems to ignore the `ON column = constant` predicate of a `LEFT JOIN` for the *left* table. It does enforce `ON column = constant` for the *right* table, though.

If I move the left table's `ON column = constant` to the `WHERE` clause instead, the query works as intended.

Why does it matter, for the left table, whether I place the `column = constant` in the `WHERE` part of the query, or in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`?

(What happens, is that the left table `ON column = constant` condition gets pushed up to a "JOIN Filter" step, where it is seemingly being ignored.)

**Details:**

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select * from DW1_PAGE_PATHS t left join DW1_PAGES g
   on t.TENANT = g.TENANT
  and t.PAGE_ID = g.GUID
  and g.GUID = 'abcdefg'  -- works
  and t.CANONICAL = 'C'  -- "ignored", unless moved to `where` clause
where t.TENANT = '72'
  and PARENT_FOLDER like '/%';
```

Here (below) is the exec plan. Note that `t.CANONICAL = 'C'` has been pushed up to the "JOIN Filter" step, whereas the `g.GUID = 'abcdefg'` filter happens directly when the right table is being scanned.

```
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=... actual time=...)
   Join Filter: (((t.canonical)::text = 'C'::text)
             AND ((t.tenant)::text = (g.tenant)::text)
             AND ((t.page_id)::text = (g.guid)::text))
   ->  Seq Scan on dw1_page_paths t
         Filter: (((parent_folder)::text ~~ '/%'::text)
              AND ((tenant)::text = '72'::text))
   ->  Seq Scan on dw1_pages g
         Filter: (((tenant)::text = '72'::text)
              AND ((guid)::text = 'abcdefg'::text))
```

(Another question: Why won't the "Join Filter" with *t.canonical = 'C'* filter out rows for which *canonical* is not 'C'?  It does not.)

PostgreSQL version: `psql (9.1.6, server 9.1.1)`

Here is a link to a similar query, but the answers don't explain *why* it works if you move the left table `ON column = constant` to a `where` clause instead:

- [Add condition while using LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147943/add-condition-while-using-left-outer-join)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ON` clause of a [`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) only regulates whether 0  or more row(s) from the right table are joined. (Possibly multiplying output rows.)

It does **not** filter rows from the left table. If you want that, the expression has to go into a `WHERE` clause (as you found out already) or the `ON` clause of an `[INNER] JOIN`.

Of course, a `WHERE` condition makes nonsense of a `LEFT JOIN` on the same table, as that's now forced to act as a plain `JOIN`.

That's all by design. Standard SQL.

Comment: This is by design, for standard SQL? (Not just PostgreSQL?)

Comment: @KajMagnus: Standard SQL. Works the same way in other RDBMS.