# How can I make my PostgreSQL select query shorter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am working on the website and I need to execute a pretty complex select query. I managed to write it, but It looks too long for me and I want to make it shorter. Here is my query:

```sql
select friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address
from (select friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address, count(friend_id) as rents
      from (select friend.friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address
            from friend
                     left join profile p on friend.profile_id = p.profile_id
                     left join friend_group_record fgr on friend.friend_id = fgr.friend_id
                     left join meeting m on fgr.friend_group_id = m.friend_group_id
            where m.date between '2019-09-01' and '2020-01-01') as filtered_friend_profiles
      group by friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address) as counted_friend_profiles
where counted_friend_profiles.rents >= 25;
```

Does anyone have idea how to make it shorter?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but it seems this the same query:
SELECT f.friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address
FROM friend f
LEFT JOIN profile p ON f.profile_id = p.profile_id
LEFT JOIN friend_group_record fgr ON f.friend_id = fgr.friend_id
LEFT JOIN meeting m ON fgr.friend_group_id = m.friend_group_id
WHERE m.date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
HAVING COUNT(friend_id) >= 25

Comment: Please add table qualification for these columns in the inner SELECT list to make it unambiguous: `name, surname, mail, birth_date, address`. And always disclose your version of Postgres. Ideally, we also need basic table definitions for involved tables showing data types and constraints - even if much can be guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter? (And correct?!)

```
SELECT f.friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address  -- ⑤
FROM   friend f
JOIN   profile p USING (profile_id)  -- ①
JOIN   friend_group_record fgr ON f.friend_id = fgr.friend_id  -- also USING?
JOIN   meeting m ON fgr.friend_group_id = m.friend_group_id  -- also USING?
WHERE  m.date >= '2019-09-01'  -- ②
AND    m.date <  '2020-01-01'
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  -- ③
HAVING count(*) >= 25;  -- ④
```

① Changed all three instances of `LEFT JOIN` to `[INNER] JOIN`, since the condition on the last table in the food chain (`meeting`) forces all joins to behave like plain joins anyway. (As @wildplasser pointed out.) See:

- [PostgreSQL: Using AND statement in LEFT JOIN is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793422/postgresql-using-and-statement-in-left-join-is-not-working-as-expected/40795634#40795634)
- [SQL / PostgreSQL left join ignores "on = constant" predicate, on left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699945/sql-postgresql-left-join-ignores-on-constant-predicate-on-left-table/13701007#13701007)

Also, if column names are identical and distinct among all tables left of the join, [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) is convenient short syntax. (Returning only *one* of each pair of joined columns, which has no bearing on the query at hand.)

Not knowing exact table definitions, I only applied it in the first join, where ambiguities are impossible as there is only a single table left of the join. For persisted queries, generally only advisable if involved column names are stable and distinct over all joined tables.

② Typically, you'd want to exclude the upper bound and [`BETWEEN` is the wrong tool](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29). Related:

- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267877/3684)
- [POSTGRES select n equally distributed rows by time over millions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385262/postgres-select-n-equally-distributed-rows-by-time-over-millions-of-records/61419141#61419141)
- [How do I write a function in plpgsql that compares a date with a timestamp without time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004811/how-do-i-write-a-function-in-plpgsql-that-compares-a-date-with-a-timestamp-witho/62020050#62020050)

③ About this short syntax:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Possibly shorter if there are functional dependencies with PK columns. See:

- [Why can't I exclude dependent columns from `GROUP BY` when I aggregate by a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095987/why-cant-i-exclude-dependent-columns-from-group-by-when-i-aggregate-by-a-key/62096322#62096322)

④ `count(*)` is shorter & faster (and equivalent in this case). Also, can be used in `HAVING` clause without listing in `SELECT` list. See:

- [Postgres: count(*) vs count(id)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41097/3684)

⑤ All source column names should be table-qualified, if only for documentation. Also avoids breakage and confusion from later changes to underlying tables.

Comment: Note: `LEFT   JOIN meeting m ON fgr.friend_group_id = m.friend_group_id  -- also USING?
WHERE  m.date >= '2019-09-01' ...`  is a classic mistake. (and: in this case, it will cascade through all the (LEFT) joins)

Comment: @wildplasser: Oh, yes, bingo. That one slipped through.

Answer (score 1):

How about just doing this?

```
select friend.friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address
from friend
left join profile p on friend.profile_id = p.profile_id
left join friend_group_record fgr on friend.friend_id = fgr.friend_id
left join meeting m on fgr.friend_group_id = m.friend_group_id
where m.date between '2019-09-01' and '2020-01-01'
group by friend.friend_id, name, surname, mail, birth_date, address
having count(friend.friend_id) >= 25;
```

See the addition of `having` clause.