# Error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have the following 3 tables:

airport

```
airport_id  name
1           Frankfurt
2           Paris
3           Amsterdam
```

area

```
areaid    name    airport_id
1         name1   2
2         name2   2
3         name3   3
4         name4   3
```

booking

```
id      booking_date        price   commission  areaid
1       2022-09-1T10:00     70      12          1
2       2022-09-2T11:00     60      16          2
3       2022-09-2T20:00     50      15          3
4       2022-09-3T01:00     110     15          3
5       2022-09-10T22:00    90      14          4
6       2022-09-11T19:00    65      12          1
7       2022-09-20T12:00    84      16          2
```

And I have this query

```
SELECT ar.name,
     (SELECT (b.price * b.commission) AS com
        FROM booking AS b
        LEFT JOIN area AS p ON b.areaid = p.areaid
        AND p.areaid = 3
        AND (b.booking_date >= '2022-09-01T00:00' AND b.booking_date <= '2022-09-30T23:59:59')
      )
FROM airport AS ar WHERE ar.airport_id = 2
```

Running the query I get the error:

> ```
> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> ```

I don't understand what the problem is.

I added an  SQL Fiddle to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8a09f/1

Comment: No images for text data, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery in the `SELECT` list is only allowed to return a **single value**. Not multiple rows, nor multiple columns. If you want any of those, the standard replacement is a `LATERAL` subquery. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

The more severe problem with your query is that it doesn't make sense at all.

This *might* be what you want, returning the list of all commissions (if any) for a given airport and a given area:

```sql
SELECT ar.name AS airport, b.com
FROM   airport ar
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT b.price * b.commission / 100.0 AS com
   FROM   area    p
   JOIN   booking b USING (areaid)
   WHERE  p.airport_id = ar.airport_id  -- my assumption
   AND    p.areaid = 3
   AND    b.booking_date >= '2022-09-01'
   AND    b.booking_date <  '2022-10-01'
   ) b ON true
WHERE  ar.airport_id = 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m-JAQ_qM)

(But you get no results for `com` while asking for airport *2* and area *3*, for which there are no matching entries.)

Your subquery was **uncorrelated**. Assuming you really meant to link to the given airport via `airport_id`.

`LEFT JOIN area AS p` made no sense in combination with the condition `WHERE p.areaid = 3`. That's a hidden `[INNER] JOIN`. See:

- [SQL / PostgreSQL left join ignores "on = constant" predicate, on left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699945/sql-postgresql-left-join-ignores-on-constant-predicate-on-left-table/13701007#13701007)

The filter `b.booking_date <= '2022-09-30T23:59:59'` may be slightly incorrect, too (unless your data is guaranteed to have a 1-minute resolution). Either way, `b.booking_date < '2022-10-01'` is the proper way to include "all of September". `'2022-10-01'` is a valid `timestamp` literal, short for `'2022-10-01T00:00:00'`.

Assuming the value in `commission` is really meant to be a percentage. (But I removed the rounding I first had. You didn't ask for that.)

BTW, if you actually want the **sum** - a single value - a **correlated (!) subquery** becomes an option again:

```sql
SELECT ar.name AS airport
     , (SELECT sum(b.price * b.commission) / 100.0
        FROM   area    p
        JOIN   booking b USING (areaid)
        WHERE  p.airport_id = ar.airport_id
        AND    p.areaid = 3
        AND    b.booking_date >= '2022-09-01'
        AND    b.booking_date <  '2022-10-01') AS com
FROM   airport ar
WHERE  ar.airport_id = 2;
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. I want all the commissions for a given airport and a given area. Actually I need more, the sum of all these commissions. But for simplicity I omitted that for now. The booking_date is of type `timestamp without time zone`. Unfortunately your query returns the right name for airport but `null` for the commission `com`

Comment: @codyLine That's because there are no rows for airport 2 and area 3 in your example. Also goes to show that the sum is actually simpler than the list. `timestamp` is the short name for `timestamp without time zone`, so my assimption is correct there, too. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860

Comment: OK, I rerun my query and I get indeed plenty of results but only when I remove the condition `b.areaid = 3`. Why ?

Comment: I tried also with `p` instead of `b`; `p.areaid = 3`. Same result

Comment: Oh, I just see your comment. No, there is plenty of bookings for area 3 and airport 2. No matter what area I choose, I get no results.

Comment: Plenty of bookings? In the given time frame? My query is solid. And my crystal ball is all out of juice. (`p.areaid = 3` is idempotent to `b.areaid = 3` in this query, btw.)

Comment: I meant my real data. I created a fresh test DB with the exact data like above. I run your code and please have a look at my screenshots in my edited question above. I also shared code to create the DB.

Comment: All I said holds. Consider my update. (Next time, please start the question with the fiddle.)

Answer (score 1):

The query

```sql
SELECT (b.price * b.commission) AS com
    FROM booking AS b
    LEFT JOIN area AS p ON b.areaid = p.areaid
    AND p.areaid = 3
    AND (b.booking_date >= '2022-09-01T00:00' AND b.booking_date <= '2022-09-30T23:59:59')
```

returns 7 rows. A subquery used in the `SELECT` list must return no more than 1 row.

A natural way to get what you want is to join all tables, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
    ar.name,
    (b.price * b.commission) AS com
FROM airport AS ar
LEFT JOIN area AS p 
    ON ar.airport_id = p.airport_id
LEFT JOIN booking AS b 
    ON b.areaid = p.areaid
    AND p.areaid = 3
    AND b.booking_date >= '2022-09-01T00:00' 
    AND b.booking_date <= '2022-09-30T23:59:59'
```

Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN` to skip rows with null results.

Comment: For me, the most important condition `ar.airport_id = 2` is missing in your statement.

Comment: The query for `ar.airport_id = 2` returns no rows with not-null `com`, which results directly from the sample data. Of course, you can add any condition you want in the `WHERE` clause to the end of the query.

Comment: Your query works only when I remove `p.areaid = 3` condition. Strange.